# GET request with data in body

Tags: rest, asp.net-web-api

I'm implementing an API endpoint that serves data but makes no modifications to data - it's something along the lines of "GET all items that match this list of filters", where a filter could be something like "ID > 200" or "propertyA != null".

In actual implementation, I have to send an array to the endpoint, specifying a bunch of resources on a per-id basis to GET back to the client.  Something like

```
GET api/tickets

{
    ids: [1, 3, 5, 7, 9],
    filter: "on-sale"
}
```

From what I understand, a Restfully implemented api would not use GET for this kind of request as it's expected that only the id of the target resource is specified in the url, with no contents in the body.

Though I hate to think I would have to hamfist this thing into a PUT or POST request.

What's the right thing to do here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTTP does not allow you to sending meaningful information in the GET body.  You can however send lists in the request URI.

This URI is perfectly valid.

```
GET /tickets?ids=1,3,5,7,9&filter=on-sale
```

Comment: +1 The Resource that is returned by a HTTP `GET` request must be identyfieable *only* by the URL. No information at other places in the request must be necessary for this.

Besides HTTP `GET` not allowing data in the body, this data must be ignored to identify the requested resource.